# Double integral containing $e^{(b+ic)/z^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I want to solve the two integrals
\begin{aligned}
I_3\,& = \int_{0}^{\infty} ze^{a/z^2 - z^2} dz\\
I_4\,& = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z}e^{a/z^2 - z^2} dz.
\end{aligned}
where 
\begin{aligned}
a\,& = b + ic\\
b,c\,& \in \mathbb{R}\\
b &\,< 0.
\end{aligned}

With this knowledge I will then try to solve the following integrals (but that is a separate problem):

\begin{aligned}
I_1\,&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\int_{0}^{\infty}dy\frac{x^2+y^2-\frac{3}{2}}{2x^2+y^2}y\cdot e^{-(x^2+y^2)}e^{a/(2x^2+y^2)}\\
I_2\,&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\int_{0}^{\infty}dy\frac{y}{2x^2+y^2}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}e^{a/(2x^2+y^2)},
\end{aligned}
The main difficulty arises from the term $e^{a/(x^2+y^2)}$, since $e^{a/x}$ has an essential singularity about $x=0$. I am pretty sure that I am not interested in this point anyway, so it might be safe to assume the boundary condition $I_{1,2} = 0$ at origo.

**Edit:** I noticed that @Vladimir actually answered my original question, so it was only right that I made a roll-back and accept the answer. Progress in $I_{1,2}$ might be posted in a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two hints:

(1) $\frac{dI_3}{da}=I_4$.

(2) In $I_4$ make the change of variables $z^2=\eta$ and then $\eta=\xi\sqrt{a}$. Then you get 
$$
 I_4=2\int_0^{\infty e^{-i\operatorname{arg}a/2}} e^{\sqrt{a}(\eta^{-1}-\eta)}\frac{d\eta}{\eta}=2\int_0^\infty e^{\sqrt{a}(\eta^{-1}-\eta)}\frac{d\eta}\eta
$$
(the last equality by Jordan's lemma)
$$
 =4\int_0^1 e^{\sqrt{a}(\eta^{-1}-\eta)}\frac{d\eta}\eta,
$$
and then note that the integral gives (modulo the $2\pi$ factor) the Bessel function of order zero.

Comment: I have two questions related to this answer: Q1. Are the indefinite integrals of $I_3$ and $I_4$ well defined? I also want to evaluate $I_3$ and $I_4$ with an additional term $\text{Erfi}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ in the integrand. Q2. How is it apparent that the last step is valid, i.e. rewriting the upper integration limit from $\infty$ to $1$?

Comment: Q1. I do no quite understand what you mean by "idefinite integrals of $I_3$ and $I_4$", but the improper definite $I_3$ and $I_4$ themselves are well defined as oscillatory integrals. Q2. $\int_0^1=\int_1^\infty$ via the change of variables $\eta\to\frac1\eta$.

Comment: Q1. Sorry if I was a bit unclear. I mean the anti-derivative, or the primitive function, to the integrand (not evaluated over the integration range). I updated the original post with the final step I have to do to solve the entire problem (solving $I_5$ and $I_6$). An idea I have is to try partial integration, but for that I need the indefinite integrals/primitive function of the integrand in $I_3$ and $I_4$. Maybe this is not the best way to solve integrals $I_5$ and $I_6$, if you know how to solve them I would be really happy to know how.

Comment: About $I_{5,6}$ no idea, sorry.